# React Router: browserHistory.push() vs this.context.router.push()

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've been learning React along with Redux, and have noticed two ways to change the URL programmatically (not using `<Link>`) when using React-Router.

One way is to push directly to `browserHistory`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

class Name extends React.Component {
    gotoPage() {
        browserHistory.push('/page');
    }
    render() {
       return <div onClick={this.gotoPage.bind(this)}>Hello</div>
    }
}
```

The other is to push to `this.context.router`.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

class Name extends React.Component {
    static contextTypes = {
        router: PropTypes.object
    };
    gotoPage() {
        this.context.router.push('/page');
    }
    render() {
       return <div onClick={this.gotoPage.bind(this)}>Hello</div>
    }
}
```

Should I use one over the other?

Comment: Specifically read Felipe Skinner's answer.